# MVC: Retrieving value from input from view to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I know it might seem a repeated problem. But i have created this form and i want to get the value of the email field in order to generate it to qr code 
so this is the view

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Registration form</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php $attributes = array("name" => "registrationform");
                echo form_open("user/register", $attributes);?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">First Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Your First Name" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('fname'); ?>" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('fname'); ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Last Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('lname'); ?>" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('lname'); ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email ID</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email-ID" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject">Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('cpassword'); ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Signup</button>
                    <button name="cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                </div>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
          </div>
          </div>
         </div>
```

The controller: 
This is a function that inserts data into the data base and it redirects to another function (successInsert)

```
function register()
    {
        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[cpassword]|md5');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|md5');

        //validate form input
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // fails
            $this->load->view('user_registration_view');
        }
        else
        {
            //insert the user registration details into database
            $data = array(
                'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );

            // insert form data into database
            if ($this->User_model->insertUser($data))
            {
                redirect('user/successInsert');
         }
}



    function successInsert()
            {
                $data['email'] = $this->input->post("email");  
                $this->load->view('successful',$data);
            }
```

//This function redirects to view called successful only with the email
And yet i still can't echo the email. Any help please.

Comment: `set_value()` only works with form library https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: Just as a side note for your `form_error()`, you can set the form error delimiters once and not have to do it separately for each error http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#changing-the-error-delimiters

Comment: @Saty: Form Library is already loaded from controller. What shall i do next?

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting the user to another page which does not keep the `POST` data intact. I would suggest just loading the view, `$this->load->view('successful',$data);`, instead of the redirect thus keeping everything in one function.

**Note:** I am not sure what happens inside your `User_model->insertUser()` function but make sure you escape your raw data before inserting it into any database.

Comment: Thanks James. This sure did the trick. Any suggestions how to convert to qr code ?

Comment: From a quick Google search you could either 1. use a QR code library for CodeIgniter such as https://github.com/dwisetiyadi/CodeIgniter-PHP-QR-Code or 2. use a third-party API such as http://goqr.me/api/

Comment: Thanks James. The second one did the charm. How may i repay you Sir? Many thanks :)

Comment: You should accept the answer if this solved the problem :)

Answer (score -1):

Change your form action

```
  <?php $attributes = array("name" => "registrationform");
            echo form_open("user/register", $attributes);?>
```

To:

```
 <?php $attributes = array("name" => "registrationform");
            echo form_open("user/successInsert", $attributes);?>
```

Comment: register is the function to insert successInsert is a function that redirects to another view with only the email. Check the edit